# Set html attributes with data annotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I set attributes when my model property is rendered with any Html helper?
Example:
I have my custom data annotation:

```
[MyCustomAttribute(AnyHtmlProperty = "100")]
public string Name{get;set;}
```

So, when this property is rendered, I want something like this:

```
<input type="text" anyHtmlProperty="100" />
```

Comment: Excellent question. Can't find the answer anywhere!

Answer (score 1):

You could write an HtmlHelper extension method which accepts an expression. Here's a non-functioning example of what the razor syntax would look like.

```
@Html.CustomInputFor(x => x.Name)
```

Comment: Yeah, it's nice, but I want to understand how ValidationAttributes render html.

Comment: A good place to look on how to implement something like this would be the MVC source code which generates the unobtrusive validation attributes.

You can see it here: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/540cccefebf9#src%2fSystem.Web.Mvc%2fHtmlHelper.cs

Just search for `GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes`

Comment: I'm looking it, so HtmlHelper call this to render correct? but how can I now configure the metadata in my custom annotation?